# in-app billing: What is the "kind" field in a subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

When you fetch entries from the Google Play Developer API, you get a [Subscription resource](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource). I don't understand what the "kind" field is:

> This kind represents a subscriptionPurchase object in the
>   androidpublisher service.

What does that mean? Can anybody give me an example what the result look like?

Answer (score 0):

google play develoepr api depends on google cloud sub/pub,this is a gcloud publisher which publish the message.